# How to make morris donut chart with ajax json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, donut-chart

How to make morris donut chart with ajax json ?

this is my code :

```
$(function() {

$.ajax({
    url : 'dashboard/total-data',    
}).done(function(data){
    initDonut(JSON.parse(data));
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(){

});

var initDonut = function(data){

    return Morris.Donut({
        element: 'morris-donut-chart',
        data: [ data ],
        // data: [ 
                // {label: "BMW", value: 4},
                // {label: "Mercy", value: 0},
                // {label: "Ferrari", value: 0},
                // {label: "Toyota", value: 3},
                // {label: "Porsche", value: 0},
                // {label: "Limosin", value: 0},
                // {label: "Lamborgini", value: 3} ],
        resize: true,
        colors: ['#87d6c6', '#54cdb4','#1ab394', '#54cdb4','#1ab394', '#54cdb4','#1ab394'],
    });

} });
```

Ajax code above return data format like this:

```
{"BMW":4,"Mercy":0,"Ferrari":0,"Toyota":3,"Porsche":0,"Limosin":0,"Lamborgini":3}
```

my question,

How to make format data above become like this with javascript?

```
[ {label: "BMW", value: 4},{label: "Mercy", value: 0},{label: "Ferrari", value: 0},{label: "Toyota", value: 3},{label: "Porsche", value: 0},{label: "Limosin", value: 0},{label: "Lamborgini", value: 3} ]
```

This is code for show json:

```
public function total_data()
{
    $data['BMW']        = $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_bmw();
    $data['Mercy']      = $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_mercy();
    echo json_encode($data);
    $data['Ferrari']    = $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_ferrari();
    $data['Toyota']     = $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_toyota();
    $data['Porsche']    = $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_porsche();
    $data['Limosin']    = $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_limosin();
    $data['Lamborgini'] = $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_lamborgini();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: show `total-data` code? because json made there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change code of `total-data` like below:-

```
public function total_data()
{
    $data[0]['label']= 'BMW'; 
    $data[0]['value']= $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_bmw();

    $data[1]['label']= 'Mercy'; 
    $data[1]['value']= $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_mercy();


    $data[2]['label']= 'Ferrari'; 
    $data[2]['value']=  $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_ferrari();

    $data[3]['label']= 'Toyota'; 
    $data[3]['value']=  $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_toyota();

    $data[4]['label']= 'Porsche'; 
    $data[4]['value']=  $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_porsche();

    $data[5]['label']= 'Limosin'; 
    $data[5]['value']=  $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_limosin();

    $data[6]['label']= 'Lamborgini'; 
    $data[6]['value']=  $this->m_dashboard->get_total_product_lamborgini();

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

***jQuery code need to be:-***

```
$(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url : 'dashboard/total-data',    
    }).done(function(data){
        Morris.Donut({
          element: 'morris-donut-chart',
          data: JSON.parse(data),
           resize: true,
           colors: ['#87d6c6', '#54cdb4','#1ab394', '#54cdb4','#1ab394', '#54cdb4','#1ab394']
        });

    }).fail(function(){

    });
});
```

***Working at my end:-*** http://prntscr.com/f6399z

Comment: thanks, thats working very well.. you save my day.. :)

Comment: @silviazulinka  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the question is mostly, how do I get from

```
{key: foo, key2:bar}
```

to

```
[{label: key, value:foo},{label: key2, value:bar}]
```

I'm a huge fan of libraries like lodash and [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs). If you had Ramda available I would recommend something like:

```js
var input = {
  "BMW": 4,
  "Mercy": 0,
  "Ferrari": 0,
  "Toyota": 3,
  "Porsche": 0,
  "Limosin": 0,
  "Lamborgini": 3
}
var expected = [{
  label: "BMW",
  value: 4
}, {
  label: "Mercy",
  value: 0
}, {
  label: "Ferrari",
  value: 0
}, {
  label: "Toyota",
  value: 3
}, {
  label: "Porsche",
  value: 0
}, {
  label: "Limosin",
  value: 0
}, {
  label: "Lamborgini",
  value: 3
}]


// First thing we want is to group the key and value together
var pairs = R.toPairs(input);

// This gives us something like
// [["BMW",4],["Mercy",0],...]

// This is getting a little far to explain here but Ramda
// curries all it's functions so we can pass the labels
// here and then the pairs later.
var label = R.zipObj(["label", "value"]);

// Here we map the label function over each set of pairs
var output = pairs.map(label);

tape('Same?', t => {
  t.deepEqual(expected, output);
  t.end();
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.23.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/tape@latest"></script>
```

Otherwise, you could do something in a for loop.

```js
var input = {
  "BMW": 4,
  "Mercy": 0,
  "Ferrari": 0,
  "Toyota": 3,
  "Porsche": 0,
  "Limosin": 0,
  "Lamborgini": 3
}
var expected = [{
  label: "BMW",
  value: 4
}, {
  label: "Mercy",
  value: 0
}, {
  label: "Ferrari",
  value: 0
}, {
  label: "Toyota",
  value: 3
}, {
  label: "Porsche",
  value: 0
}, {
  label: "Limosin",
  value: 0
}, {
  label: "Lamborgini",
  value: 3
}]
var output = [];
for (var k in input) {
  output.push({"label": k, "value": input[k]});
}

tape('Same?', t => {
  t.deepEqual(expected, output);
  t.end();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/tape@latest"></script>
```